# How to tag the count of TP,TN, FP,FN as per the different classes in multiclass classification?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have written a code which calculates the count of TP,TN,FP,FN of multiclass classifier using scikit learn. The problem I am facing is I want to represent this count every class wise like this below:

```
Actual    Predicted
iphone      iphone
samsung     sony
Sony        sony
bmw         audi
```

I want the count of all tn,tp,fn,fp classwise like for example:

```
          tp   tn  tn  tp
bmw       25   15  40  50
samsung   20   28  35  55
```

This is how my code looks:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

#reading the input file
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\test.xlsx')

#Converting the columns to array
actual = df['Actual'].to_numpy()
predicted = df['Predicted'].to_numpy()


mcm = multilabel_confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)
#print(mcm)

tn = mcm[:, 0, 0]
tp = mcm[:, 1, 1]
fn = mcm[:, 1, 0]
fp = mcm[:, 0, 1]

print(tn,tp,fn,fp)
```

Output looks like this which is just tn,tp,fn,fp count of 19 classes

```
array([182, 569, 568, 569, 545, 429, 566, 516, 504, 568, 534, 437, 567,
       569, 569, 569, 569, 567, 569], dtype=int64), array([111,   0,   0,   0,   7,  21,   0,   7,  37,   0,  15,  78,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0], dtype=int64), array([ 48,   0,   0,   0,  16, 117,   0,  47,  17,   0,  13,  36,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0], dtype=int64), array([229,   1,   2,   1,   2,   3,   4,   0,  12,   2,   8,  19,   3,
         1,   1,   1,   1,   3,   1], dtype=int64))
```

How can I achieve this tagging of each 18 with count as per the individual class?

Comment: May be [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)?

Comment: From confusion matrix I took the tp,tn,fp,fn values of each class but the problem is i want to map each count to their respective class which i am not able to do and from confusion matrix it i not happening

Comment: use `labels=df['Actual'].unique();mcm = multlabel_confusion_matrix(actual, predicted, labels=labels)`, then the rows are labeled as ordered in `labels`.

Comment: I am able to get the unique classes which have non zero values here...so to get the entire stuff (that is classes and their respective tp,tn,fp,fn)in a single dataframe i have to insert all in the different columns to a new dataframe?

Comment: after the commands above, do `pd.DataFrame(mcm, index=labels)`.

Comment: Getting value error while executing ```pd.DataFrame(mcm, index=labels)``` this is the error ```  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 171, in init_ndarray
    values = prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 295, in prep_ndarray
    raise ValueError("Must pass 2-d input")
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(mcm.reshape(-1,4),label=labels)`?

Comment: Or `pd.DataFrame({'tn': mcm[:,0,0],...})`.

Comment: for ```pd.DataFrame(mcm.reshape(-1,4),label=labels)``` getting error File "try.py", ```line 25, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(mcm.reshape(-1,4),label=labels)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label' ```

Comment: Sorry `index=labels` not `label=labels`.

Comment: using ```pd.DataFrame({'tn': mcm[:,0,0],...},index=labels)``` I was able to achieve result..is this correct?